# Redirect :80 to :443 (http to https) with Wakanda Server

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, wakanda

I've set up a Wakanda server hosted on an Amazon EC2 instance, that has SSL certificates installed as per the Wakanda documentation and accessing the home page via https easily enough, but won't redirect incoming traffic on port 80 to 443 automatically.

Being an Amazon AWS instance with an elastic IP, I've tried to set up a load balancer to handle the traffic routing for me as a possible solution. Though while that reports that it's routing "Load Balancer Port = 80" to "Instance Port = 443", it doesn't seem to be redirecting traffic either.

I may be missing something entirely in the way the Load Balancer is supposed to work, but is there a way for the Wakanda Server to automatically route incoming http traffic to https? Edit: I have also tried to set up a .htaccess file in my webFolder directory to manually try to redirect traffic, though I'm finding very limited documentation around whether that is a viable option in itself too.

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding two listener one for 80 - 443 and another for 443 - 443. You must install same certificate in the loadbalancer too.

Comment: Hey @kavin, thanks for the response! I've actually got the LB set up like that: https://i.imgur.com/l5a9K66.png ... Is that how you'd usually expect to see it configured?

Comment: Is the setup working fine with http? AWS ELB redirect is simple, you can check the redirect by enabling the elb logs to get more information on that.

Comment: To an extent - our application has it locked down so no http connections are active, it only listens on a secure port. So when accessing via http it does as I expect if it was to go straight to port 80 - get an error - however I was hoping I could have it direct all traffic to https itself without needing to redirect on an application level. I'll go through the logs though